# Create file in specified directory

Tags: java, android, eclipse, outputstream, fileoutputstream

Try to create file in specific directory but it shows the error FileNotFound. Why?
Am I using impossible path? I really don't know, but is seems like the code should be working.

```
    String day=/1;
String zn="/zn";
    File_name=zn
String root= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();            
    File_path=root+day;

        File file1 = new File(File_path,File_name);
        file1.mkdirs();
        if(!file1.exists()) {
            try {
                file1.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } 


        try {
            OutputStream fos= new FileOutputStream(file1);
            String l,d,p;
            l = lessnum.getText().toString();
            d = desc.getText().toString();
            p = place.getText().toString();

            fos.write(l.getBytes());
            fos.write(d.getBytes());
            fos.write(p.getBytes());

            fos.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your code as for creating a file on sdcard

```
String root= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
String File_name = "File_name.Any_file_Extension(like txt,png etc)";


File file1 = new File(root+ File.separator + File_name);
if(!file1.exists()) {
    try {
         file1.createNewFile();
       } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
}
```

In current you you are also missing file  Extension with file name so change String `zn` as `zn="/zn.txt";`

and make sure you have added Sd card permission in `AndroidManifest.xml` :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: yes and also add folder path with it if folder is already exit

Comment: so and if all my path is 2 strigs  like 
dirName = root + should i put here : File.separator +day ;

Comment: @user1872357 : what is `day` it's dir or file?

Comment: @user1872357 :you can use as if day is folder on sdcard `File file1 = new File(root+ File.separator + day + File.separator + File_name);` or `File file1 = new File(root+ "/" + day + "/" + File_name);`

Comment: day - is folder so file must be: root/day/zn.txt

Answer (score 1):

First you make a directory

```
String root= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();      
 String dirName =
     root+ "abc/123/xy"; 
     File newFile =  new File(dirName);
     newFile.mkdirs();
```

then you create a file inside that directory

`String testFile = "test.txt";
         File file1 = new File(dirName,testFile);
        if(!file1.exists()){
             try {
                file1.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }`

then do your file writing operations

```
try { OutputStream fos= new FileOutputStream(file1);
```

String l,d,p; 
l = lessnum.getText().toString(); 
d = desc.getText().toString();
 p = place.getText().toString(); 
os.write(l.getBytes());
fos.write(d.getBytes());
 fos.write(p.getBytes());
 fos.close();
}
 catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

I think this will help you...

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

you will need to give your app the correct permission to write to the SD Card by adding the line below to your Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

And check http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29

Answer (score 0):

```
String root= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();      
     String dirName =
         root+ "abc/123/xy"; 
         File newFile =  new File(dirName);
         newFile.mkdirs();

         String testFile = "test.txt";
         File file1 = new File(dirName,testFile);
        if(!file1.exists()){
             try {
                file1.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

And and `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`
 on manifest file...

Thanks...

Comment: File_path=root+File.separator+day;
   File f_dir = new File(File_path);
   f_dir.mkdirs();
   
   File file1 = new File(f_dir,File_name);
   if(!file1.exists()) {
    try {
     file1.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
   } 
   
   
   try {
    OutputStream fos= new FileOutputStream(file1);
    String l,d,p;
    l = lessnum.getText().toString();
    d = desc.getText().toString();
    p = place.getText().toString();
    
    fos.write(l.getBytes());
    fos.write(d.getBytes());
    fos.write(p.getBytes());
    
    fos.close();

Comment: i want to create file zn.txt in directory : root/day

Comment: day - is folder
so file must be: root/day/zn.txt

Answer (score 0):

Here is your latest attempt:

```
File_path = root + File.separator + day; 
File f_dir = new File(File_path); 
f_dir.mkdirs(); 
File file1 = new File(f_dir, File_name); 
if (!file1.exists()) { 
    try { 
        file1.createNewFile(); 
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    } 
}
try { 
    OutputStream fos= new FileOutputStream(file1);
```

If you showed us the *complete* stacktrace and error message it would be easier to figure out what is going wrong, but I can think of a couple of possibilities:

1. You are not checking the value returned by `f_dir.mkdirs()`, and it could well be returning `false` to indicate that the directory path was not created.  This could mean that:

   - The directory already existed.
   - Something existed but it wasn't a directory.
   - Some part of the directory path could not be created ... for one of a number of possible reasons.
2. The `file1.exists()` call will return `true` if *anything* exists with that pathname given by the object.  The fact that something exists doesn't necessarily mean that you can open it for writing:

   - It could be a directory.
   - It could be a file that the application doesn't have write permissions for.
   - It could be a file on a read-only file system.
   - And a few other things.

---

If I was writing this, I'd write it something like this:

```
File dir = new File(new File(root), day);
if (!dir.exists()) {
    if (!dir.mkdirs()) {
        System.err.println("Cannot create directories");
        return;
    }
}
File file1 = new File(dir, fileName);
try (OutputStream fos= new FileOutputStream(file1)) {
    ...
} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
   System.err.println("Cannot open file: " + ex.getMessage());
}
```

I only attempt to create the directory if required ... and check that the creation succeeded.
Then I simply attempt to open the file to write to it.  If the file doesn't exist it will be created.  If it cannot be created, then the FileNotFoundException message should explain why.

Notice that I've also corrected the style errors you made in your choice of variable names.